# How to make chart in image or SVG element (the image or svg is filled by chart) in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, charts

[image: chart in image]

So I want to make chart just like in this image, where chart is filling only the inside of image and I want the chart to have no label at all.

I tried using chart.js library but it didn't help me and I tried to create clip mask using css and JavaScript but I give up after some tries.
the svg :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 300 300"><path d="M146.3 38.9c-13.1 3.8-24.9 13.8-31.1 26.4-2.5 5-3.8 6.7-5.4 6.7-1.1 0-3.6 1.6-5.4 3.6-3.3 3.4-3.4 3.8-3.4 11.8 0 10 2.2 14.3 8.5 16.5 3.3 1.1 4.5 2.3 6.5 6.5 1.4 2.7 4.8 7.5 7.6 10.5l5.1 5.5-3.2 7.7c-7.9 18.3-9.3 20.2-18 23.6-5.7 2.2-8.7 1.6-11.8-2.2-4.4-5.5-10.1-4.1-9.1 2.2.5 3-.4 2.9-4.9-.8-4.6-3.8-7.7-3.6-8.9.6-2.1 7.3 1.8 17.9 8 21.9 7.2 4.7 21.2 5.7 29.6 2.2 4-1.7 4.6-1.3 4.6 2.9 0 1.8.7 4.9 1.5 6.8 1 2.5 1.5 7.1 1.4 15.4 0 6.5.2 12.5.5 13.3.3.8.7 3.4 1 5.7.3 2.3 1.2 7.1 2.1 10.8 1.9 8.5 2 8.1-1.4 9.5-3.1 1.2-7.5 5.5-8.3 8.1-1 2.6 1.9 7.7 5.4 9.6 4.9 2.7 25.3 2.6 32.2-.1 7.2-2.9 7.6-4.3 7.6-30.1 0-20.8.1-21.5 2-21.5 1.6 0 2 .7 2.1 3.2.1 1.8.3 4.2.4 5.3.1 1.1.8 7.2 1.4 13.5 2.2 21.3 2.8 23.7 7.6 27.9 4.2 3.7 8.6 4.4 23.3 3.9 9.3-.2 11.5-.6 13.9-2.4 5.7-4.2 3.2-13.1-4.6-16.4-3.1-1.2-3.2-1.7-4.6-18.5-.3-2.8-.7-7.8-1.1-11.3l-.6-6.2h3.7c7.3 0 10.4-4.1 11.5-15.5.4-3.9 1.7-10.2 2.9-14 2.1-6.7 2.1-7.8 1.1-25-1.2-20.5-1.9-24.1-5.7-27.8-3.1-2.9-9.1-5.7-12.3-5.7-2.7 0-2.6-.5 1.5-5.4 1.9-2.3 4.6-6.8 6-9.9 1.9-4 3.2-5.7 4.6-5.7 1 0 3.3-1.3 5.1-2.9l3.3-2.9V86.1c0-9.7-.1-10.1-2.9-13-1.6-1.7-4.4-3.3-6.1-3.7-2.4-.4-3.4-1.3-4.4-3.9-1.6-4.4-8.8-13.7-13.7-17.6-12.4-9.9-29.9-13.3-45.1-9zm27.8 3.1c3.5 1 8.5 3.3 11.1 4.9 5.6 3.6 12.8 9.9 12.8 11.4 0 .5-.8.3-1.8-.6-3.2-2.9-14.7-7.7-22.3-9.3-15.1-3.2-36.8-.4-46.3 6.1-2 1.3-3.6 2.1-3.6 1.6 0-1.1 7.6-7.4 12.4-10.2 10.1-6 25.9-7.6 37.7-3.9zm2.8 9.6c8.6 1.9 19.2 7.7 24.1 13 5.6 6.1 5 7.6-.7 1.7-9-9.2-22.3-13.6-41.8-13.6-18.2-.1-28.6 3.3-37.7 12.1-5.2 5-6.3 4.8-2.4-.3 5.1-6.6 17.9-12.8 30.1-14.5 7.5-1.1 20-.4 28.4 1.6zm2.1 7c9 2.3 14.8 5.4 21.1 11.3l5.4 5 .4 11.6.3 11.6-3.8 7.2c-3.4 6.5-7.2 12.3-12.1 18.4-1 1.2-5.4 3.9-9.8 6-7.3 3.4-8.9 3.8-18 4.1-11.5.5-17.6-.9-26.9-6.1-7.9-4.4-8.4-6.5-.8-2.6 6.8 3.4 17.3 5.9 24.9 5.9 9.5 0 26-4.1 27.8-7 .8-1.3.5-1.3-8.3.9-16 4.1-25.9 3.7-43-1.6-9-2.8-10.7-4.3-18.2-16.3l-3.5-5.5-.2-13.8-.2-13.8 4.2-4c4.5-4.1 13.9-9.3 15.9-8.7.7.3-.6 1.2-2.9 2.1-9.5 3.8-14.4 14.6-13.2 29.3.9 11.9 2.5 11.1 2.5-1.3-.1-9.6.2-11.4 2.4-15.8 4.4-8.7 15.8-14.4 30.7-15.3l8.2-.4-2.2-2-2.2-1.9 7.5.5c4.1.3 10.4 1.3 14 2.2zm34.2 16.1c2.6 2.5 2.8 3.2 2.8 11.3 0 7.7-.2 8.9-2.2 10.7-4.3 3.8-4.4 3.7-4.4-8 .1-6.2-.2-12.4-.7-14-1-3.5.8-3.6 4.5 0zm-102.4 3.5c-1 4.2-.5 17.2.8 21.5.9 3.2-1.1 2.9-4.7-.6-2.7-2.8-2.9-3.4-2.9-11.1 0-7.7.2-8.3 2.9-11.1 4.1-4.1 5.1-3.7 3.9 1.3zm87.5 47.3c5.9 1.8 10 4.1 11.6 6.7 1.8 2.9 3 10.5 3.2 21.4l.2 9.9H210c-3.1 0-3.3-.2-6.4-9-1.8-5-4.7-11.8-6.4-15.2-1.8-3.4-3.2-6.5-3.2-6.9 0-.3 2.8-.4 6.3-.2 5.7.4 6 .4 3.2-.8-1.6-.7-4.9-1.3-7.3-1.4-4.6 0-6.4-1.9-4.2-4.5.7-.8 1.3-1.5 1.4-1.5 0 0 2.3.7 4.9 1.5zm-50.8 10c11.6 3 24.5 1.6 35.2-3.8 2.9-1.5 5.5-2.7 5.8-2.7 1 0 14.5 29.2 14.5 31.5 0 .1-2.4.1-5.2.1-2.9-.1-7.2.3-9.5.7l-4.3.9v-3.9c0-5.5-2.1-15.3-3.2-15.3-.6 0-.7 2-.4 4.7.3 2.7.8 9.2 1.2 14.6l.6 9.8-8.2-.3-8.3-.3-.3-2.9c-.6-6.2-2.6-6.9-21.6-8.2-13.8-.9-17.9-.8-20 .2-1.6.7-2.8 1-2.8.7 0-.4 8.3-28.4 9.5-32 .3-.8 2.2-.2 5.7 1.7 3 1.6 8 3.6 11.3 4.5zm-28 21.8c-1.4 4.3-2.5 8.3-2.5 9 0 .7-1.1 2.9-2.5 4.8s-2.4 4.2-2.1 5.1c1.1 4.5-19.7 6.3-27.2 2.4-3.8-2-4.7-3.6-3.8-7.1.8-3.3 3.6-3.3 3.6 0 0 2.3.3 2.5 4.8 2.5 3.8-.1 4.4-.3 2.9-1.1-1-.6-2.7-.9-3.8-.6-1.5.4-1.9 0-1.9-1.9 0-1.4-1-3-2.3-3.9-1.3-.8-2.9-2.7-3.6-4.1-.9-2.1-1.7-2.5-3.6-2.1-1.9.3-2.5 0-2.5-1.3 0-3 1.2-2.9 6.2.6 2.8 1.9 6.1 3.4 7.4 3.4 2.8 0 2.8-.1 1.3-3.4-.7-1.4-.9-3.2-.5-4.2.6-1.5.9-1.5 3.1.6 1.4 1.3 2.7 3.2 3.1 4.3.5 1.7 1.2 1.9 5.9 1.3 8.9-1 16.7-5.3 18.6-10.4.5-1.3 1.2-2.3 1.4-2 .2.2-.7 3.9-2 8.1zm-39.4 6.8c.9 1.7.7 2.8-.7 5.5-2 3.6-3.4 2.9-3.4-1.8 0-5.6 2-7.5 4.1-3.7zm49.7 3.9c-.2 4.8.2 6.5 2 8.9 1.5 2.1 2.2 4.4 2.2 7.8v4.8l-5.2-.4c-2.9-.1-5.9-.8-6.5-1.3-1.6-1.3-1.8-17.5-.2-21.5 1.2-3.2 2.6-4.3 5.7-4.3 2.1 0 2.2.4 2 6zm24-2.3c1.1 1.4 1.3 4 .8 11.1-.8 13-.9 13.2-10.6 13.2h-7.9l.1-5c0-3.3-.7-6.1-2.1-8.3-1.4-2.4-2.1-5.1-2.1-8.7v-5.3l10.2.6c8.3.4 10.5.9 11.6 2.4zm52.3 6.5c1.2 5.2 2.4 13.7 2.6 19.3.4 8.6.1 10.4-1.5 13.1-1.9 3-2.2 3.1-11.7 3.7-5.4.4-10.2.4-10.7.1-1-.6-.8-2.4.8-11.2.4-2 .2-3.2-.5-3.2-.6 0-1.1.9-1.1 2s-.4 2-1 2c-1.5 0-1.1-6.1.5-9 1-1.7 1.4-5.9 1.5-13.7 0-12.9-.9-11.9 11.7-12.2l7.1-.1 2.3 9.2zm-44.9-6.5c2.5 2.3 2.3 4-1.3 7.6l-3.1 3.1.7-4.1c.4-2.5.2-5-.5-6.2-.9-1.7-.8-2.1.6-2.1 1 0 2.6.7 3.6 1.7zm53 5.8c-.3 4.8-2 12-2.7 11.3-.4-.4-3.5-14.8-3.5-16.1 0-.5 1.5-.7 3.3-.5 3.2.3 3.2.3 2.9 5.3zm-95.8 4.4c-.7 4.5-2.7 5.1-3.2.9-.3-2.3 2.4-6.5 3.5-5.5.2.2.1 2.3-.3 4.6zm58.9-.9h4.7v9.3l-10.2-.7c-10.5-.7-11.8-1.2-11.8-5.2 0-3.5 2-4.6 7.5-4 2.8.3 7.1.6 9.8.6zm-17 9.7c2 2.2 2 2.3.2 4.3-2.3 2.6-6.1 2.8-4.9.2.4-.9.9-3.5 1.2-5.7.3-2.2.7-3.3 1-2.5.2.8 1.4 2.5 2.5 3.7zm-38 6.1c1.2.6 9.9 1.6 19.2 2.2 15.9.9 17.2.9 19.5-.9 1.4-1 2.6-2.8 2.8-3.9.3-2 .9-2.1 8.8-1.9 7 .2 8.3.4 7.8 1.7-1.5 3.7-1.6 9-.3 10.6.8.9 1.4 3.7 1.4 6.2 0 3.9.4 4.8 2.5 5.9 1.6.9 4.1 1.1 6.8.8l4.2-.6v7c0 3.9.1 7.4.3 7.8.4 1.4-12.7 4.2-20 4.2-9.6.1-10.3-.2-10.4-5.3-.1-6.5-2.3-17.9-3.6-18.3-.7-.3-.9.4-.6 1.8.6 2.2.5 2.2-7.3 1.6-12.9-1.1-21.9-4.6-28.8-11.3-4-3.9-7.6-10.5-7.5-13.9 0-1.3.5-.8 1.5 1.6.8 2 2.5 4.1 3.7 4.7zm9.9 16.5c5 2.3 10.5 3.8 18.9 5.1l3.5.6-.4 6.3c-.3 3.4-.9 6.5-1.4 6.8-4 2.6-19.6 1.4-27.4-2l-4.1-1.8-.6-8.4c-.4-4.6-.7-10.1-.7-12.2v-3.8l3.4 3.5c1.9 1.8 5.8 4.5 8.8 5.9zm7.2 22.3c3.3.3 7.9.2 10.2-.4l4.1-.9.6 10.1c.6 12-.4 19.4-2.8 21.2-4.3 3.2-21.4 4.5-30.1 2.3-2.9-.7-5.1-2.1-6.1-3.6-1.5-2.2-1.5-2.6.4-5.1 1-1.5 3.9-3.7 6.4-5 3.9-2.1 5.5-2.3 13.3-2 10.4.5 8.3-1.1-2.8-2.1l-6.9-.6-1.3-5.5c-.6-3-1.4-7.1-1.8-9.1l-.6-3.6 5.6 1.9c3.1 1 8.4 2.1 11.8 2.4zm56.6 2.1c0 1.6.3 5.1.6 7.9l.6 5.1-6.9.5c-3.8.3-7.8 1-8.9 1.6-1.4.8 0 .9 5.8.5 9.3-.7 15.3 1.2 19.3 5.9 3.1 3.6 2.9 5.4-.7 8.1-2.3 1.7-4.3 2-15 2.1-10.6.1-12.8-.2-15.7-1.9-5.6-3.3-6.9-6-8.4-18.3l-1.3-11.2 9.5-.1c5.3 0 11.6-.6 14.1-1.3 6.6-1.9 7-1.9 7 1.1z"/><path d="M155 62.8c-7.6 2.9-13 6.1-17.5 10.7-6.1 6-15.5 25.2-14.2 28.8.2.6 2.1-2.4 4.2-6.8 2-4.4 4.4-9.5 5.3-11.4 2.8-5.6 11.1-13 19.1-17.1 4.2-2.2 8.3-4.4 9.1-4.9 2.4-1.7-.6-1.3-6 .7zM187.6 78.9c-5 5.2-4.5 15.5 1 17.9 6.2 2.9 12.3-2.2 13.2-10.8.4-4.2.1-5-2.4-7.4-3.9-3.6-8.2-3.5-11.8.3zm9.8.7c1 .9 1.6 3.3 1.6 5.8 0 5.6-3 9.6-7.1 9.6-2.5 0-3.3-.6-4.5-3.6-3.3-8 4.6-17.3 10-11.8z"/><path d="M182.2 98.2c-2.5 1.2-3.7 4.6-2.8 7.6 1.8 5.4 10.6 3.9 10.6-1.9 0-6.2-2.7-8.1-7.8-5.7zm5.2 2.4c.9.8 1.6 1.7 1.6 1.9 0 1.5-1.6 3.7-3.2 4.6-3.9 2.1-6.5-3.2-3.2-6.5.8-.9 1.9-1.6 2.4-1.6s1.6.7 2.4 1.6zM134.8 136c6.5 5.4 24 8.4 35.4 6.1 5.9-1.3 18.4-6.9 17.4-7.9-.3-.3-3.8 1-7.8 2.8-12.2 5.6-29.1 5.4-41-.6-5.7-2.9-7.1-3-4-.4zM123.5 182.7c1.5 1.6 7.5 2.7 7.5 1.4 0-.6-1.1-1.1-2.4-1.1-1.3 0-3.3-.3-4.3-.6-1.2-.5-1.5-.4-.8.3zM141.6 171.6c-4.2 4.1-2.2 11.3 3.2 11.5 6.1.3 8.2-1.4 8.2-6.3 0-5.6-7.6-9.1-11.4-5.2zm5.4 2c1.9 2.2.1 6.9-2.5 6.9-3.7 0-3.1-8.4.6-8.5.4 0 1.2.7 1.9 1.6zM162.1 194c-1.3 1.1-3.5 2.1-5 2.1-1.8.1-2 .3-.8.6 2.9.7 6.5-.5 7.7-2.7 1.3-2.5 1.1-2.5-1.9 0zM150.8 206.7c1.8.2 4.5.2 6 0s0-.4-3.3-.4-4.5.2-2.7.4zM129 209c0 .4 3 2.2 6.8 4 3.7 1.8 8.4 5.1 10.5 7.3 3.7 4 5.2 3.2 1.9-1.1-1.7-2.2-19.2-11.5-19.2-10.2zM170.9 253.7c2.7 5.2 14.4 8 27.1 6.4 6.2-.8 6-.8-4.8-1-12-.1-16.6-1.3-21.1-5.4l-2.4-2.2 1.2 2.2zM70.5 102.9c-7.9 2-14.7 8.3-16.6 15.6-.6 2.2-.9 6.4-.7 9.4.4 4.8.1 5.9-2.9 10.3-3.8 5.7-4 6.9-1.5 9.1 2.4 2.2 6 2.1 12.1-.2 3.6-1.3 5.3-1.5 6.7-.8 1.1.6 4.6 1.1 7.9 1.1 6.5-.1 12.3-2.4 16.2-6.6 3-3.2 6.3-10.7 6.3-14.4 0-2 1-3.9 2.9-5.8 1.6-1.5 3.7-4.6 4.7-6.8 1.8-4 1.8-4-.5-5.9-2.6-2.2-5.1-2.3-10.1-.5-3.1 1.1-3.8 1-8-1.5-4.9-3-11.7-4.2-16.5-3zm13 4c2.2 1 5.3 3.3 6.9 5 3.5 3.6 4.7 2.2-10.6 13C70 132 61.7 137 60 137c-.5 0-1.6-1.3-2.4-2.8-8.5-16.5 9.1-35.1 25.9-27.3zm20.5 4c0 1.1-1.7 4.1-3.9 6.8-9.7 12.3-36 28.3-46.5 28.3-4.2 0-4.6-1.4-1.6-6.2 1.8-2.9 2-3 2-1.1 0 3.4 3.6 3 11.6-1.2 18.7-9.8 38.2-26.5 30.8-26.5-.8 0-1.2-.5-.9-1 .3-.6 2.4-1 4.6-1 3.2 0 3.9.4 3.9 1.9zm-10 21.3c-3 7.6-10.7 12.8-19 12.8-2.7 0-5-.5-5-1 0-.6.5-1 1.2-1 1.4 0 14-7.8 19.2-11.9 2.2-1.7 4.1-2.9 4.4-2.6.3.2-.1 1.9-.8 3.7z"/><path d="M73 110.1c-1.9 1.6-6.3 4.6-9.7 6.7-3.5 2-6.3 3.9-6.3 4.4 0 1 11.6-5.7 17.3-10 2.6-2 4.7-3.7 4.7-3.9 0-1.2-3.1.3-6 2.8zM83 111.4c-1.7 2.1-17.8 12.9-22.3 15-2.1 1-3.6 2-3.4 2.3.8.7 9.7-4 16.4-8.6 7.4-5 13.1-10 11.7-10.1-.6 0-1.7.6-2.4 1.4zM84.4 115.3c-7.6 6.5-23.7 16.4-25.6 15.9-.5-.1-.8.3-.8.8s.2 1 .5 1c2.7 0 24.4-14.1 28.4-18.4 3.4-3.6 2.2-3.3-2.5.7z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can do in inside svg, but here is  css only example, and support not the best https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image

```css
.wrapper {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dgsoeeawo/image/upload/v1689066337/umc3ddau5oljy169be_y8oyqr.svg) 100% 100% no-repeat;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .masked {
      width: 50%;
      -webkit-mask-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dgsoeeawo/image/upload/v1689066258/item_vhtwqa.svg);
      mask-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dgsoeeawo/image/upload/v1689066258/item_vhtwqa.svg);
      mask-position: bottom left;
      -webkit-mask-position: bottom left;
      opacity: .6;

    }

    .col1 {
      height: 70%;
      background-color: #8cffa0;
      mask-position: bottom left;
      -webkit-mask-position: bottom left;
    }
    .col2 {
      height: 40%;
      background-color: #da4019;
      mask-position: bottom right;
      -webkit-mask-position: bottom right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="masked col1">

    </div>
    <div class="masked col2">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It didn't work on the SVG that I provided or PNG image, it worked with your SVG file but i need to change that to SVG file that i created from PNG image

Comment: @kinan you did not provide anything, send your svg

Comment: I just edited the question and added my SVG